# Which private PHP proxy?

Tags: php, proxy

I'm looking for a private PHP proxy to put it on my hosting.

I see there is lots of them so I'm wondering if I could get a recommendation on which ones are the best? Or something like "this one is better then the rest because of: ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Glype Proxy because it's nice and simple.

You could then protect it with .htaccess to be private, just for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if I've understood you here, but I think what you're asking is something that should probably use something like Nginx instead of PHP... Take a look here http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancing